# How to call and hide lists using two buttons - using Javascript HTML CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm really struggling to get to grips with using JS. Once I have one working function i'll be winning - but getting one to work is killing me. I'm trying to use two buttons, each one calls a separate list of names. When I open the page I want one list to already show (The Sport list) and one button (Sport button) to already appear clicked, when I click the 2nd  button (Item) I want the sport list to disappear and the Item list to appear. These lists have all their styling done in CSS.

Do I store the lists in my HTML? Do I store them in the JS? I'm sure this is rather basic but I just cannot get this to work and it's driving me nuts.

Currently my code looks like this:

JS - just for one button. How would I add the 2nd button?

```
var main = function () {
    $('.Btn').click(function () {
        $('itemList').hide(200);
        $(this).children('sportList').show(200);
    })
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

HTML:

```
<!--Button Area-->
<div class="buttonArea">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="btn">Choose By Sport</div>
            <div class="btn">Choose by Item</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Sport List-->
<div class="sportList">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                <li>American Football</li>
                <li>Basketball</li>
                <li>Cricket</li>
                <li>Cycling</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Item List-->
<div class="sportList">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                    <li>Headwear</li>
                    <li>T-shirts</li>
                    <li>Gloves</li>
                    <li>Tracksuit Bottoms</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*Buttons*/
.btn {
  text-align:center;
  background: #551A8B;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #551A8B, #551A8B);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #551A8B, #551A8B);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #551A8B, #551A8B);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #551A8B, #551A8B);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #551A8B, #551A8B);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right:50px;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #808080;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #808080);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #808080);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #808080);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #808080);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #808080, #808080);
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#551A8B;
}
.buttonArea{
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align:center;
}
.buttonArea .container {
  position:relative;
  top:20px;
}
```

Lots of CSS there, probably no use to you but you never know. I've cut down the HTML lists to save some space!

I've done the Codecademy courses on this but cannot seem to translate this into something that actually works.

This:

```
<script src="Apps.js"></script>
```

also exists in my Body area.

Thanks!

Jake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More elegant way would be like this

```js
var main = function() {
  var hide_classes = ['sportList', 'itemList']; //list of classes, used by data-hideclass attribute, can be extended
  $('.' + hide_classes[0]).show(); //show only first list
  for (var k = 1; k < hide_classes.length; k++) { //hide others
    var hide_class = hide_classes[k];
    $('.' + hide_class).hide();
  }

  $('.btn').click(function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < hide_classes.length; i++) { //loop over list of classes
      var hide_class = hide_classes[i];
      if ($(this).attr('data-hideclass') === hide_class) { //if button data-hideclass is equal
        $('.' + hide_class).show(); //show list
      } else {
        $('.' + hide_class).hide(); //otherwise hide
      }
    }
  })
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
/*Buttons*/

.btn {
  text-align: center;
  background: #551A8B;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #551A8B, #551A8B);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #551A8B, #551A8B);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #551A8B, #551A8B);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #551A8B, #551A8B);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #551A8B, #551A8B);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.btn.active {
  background: #808333;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #808080);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #808080);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #808080);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #808080);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #808080, #808080);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #551A8B;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #808080;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #808080);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #808080);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #808080);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #808080, #808080);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #808080, #808080);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #551A8B;
}
.buttonArea {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.buttonArea .container {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Button Area-->
<div class="buttonArea">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="btn" data-hideclass="sportList">Choose By Sport</div>
      <div class="btn" data-hideclass="itemList">Choose by Item</div>
      <!--data-hideclass will just show only div with that class-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Sport List-->
<div class="sportList">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul style="list-style-type:none">
          <li>American Football</li>
          <li>Basketball</li>
          <li>Cricket</li>
          <li>Cycling</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Item List-->
<div class="itemList">
  <!--item class is added-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul style="list-style-type:none">
          <li>Headwear</li>
          <li>T-shirts</li>
          <li>Gloves</li>
          <li>Tracksuit Bottoms</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that this way you can extend it, and add more lists, if you desire. Just carefully read comments in js code

Comment: I owe you a beer (or anything you fancy in the local bar)! This works perfectly well and now I have this one working example I can leverage it to get much more working - without having to ask seemingly foolish questions. Many thanks!

Comment: @jmn8 I don't drink :) anyway you could upvote, it would be more pleasure

Comment: I've clicked upvote, just need 3 more rep and it'll count (i'm new here). A lemonade/lime and an upvote coming your way, i'll take that beer to celebrate. Thanks again!